# Android Studio source files not marked as source files

Tags: android, intellij-idea, gradle, android-studio

I am having a paralyzing issue with Android Studio. Whenever I use git to checkout a different branch, all of my source files (both java and xml resources) are no longer marked as source folders. The only solution I have found is to always re-import the project.

Is anyone familiar with such an issue? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can check:

- your setting.gradle if module names matches.
- your iml files inside project and inside each module. (it is case sensitive!)

You can also check ./idea/modules.xml.

Here you can find the structure of your project (and you can edit it)